# Sharepoint Workflow - No email notification once modified

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, send-email

I have created a leave request list in Sharepoint 2013. I also created workflow for it.
Here's the flow.
User will log a PTO then status set to For Approval. Email notification that i created in workflow successfully release to the recipients indicated in the form that i created in infopath.
Next, supervisor will change the status to approved. Email notification should received by user that logged the request and all recipients indicated.
THe problem is here. No email notification release by sharepoint.
The weird part is - when i logged personally indicate me as approver and all, email notification released for all the process but other user only get 1 when they logged.

I already check the workflow setting checked all in Start Options but still no luck..

Please help. THanks.

Comment: I cannot see you screenshot so just assumptions. How did you set the trigger and permission? If possible have a try to put the send Email action with issue in a App step and try again.

Comment: I dont know what screenshot i will provide to analyze the problem. What i did for the permission is the same permission what i did to my previous created list that still working right now. What do you mean by trigger?

How to do this? 
"If possible have a try to put the send Email action with issue in a App step and try again"

Comment: Would you like to provide a screenshot of the workflow itself(including actions)? Trigger means how the workflow starts, you can check the start option of the workflow with issue.